# Is there anyone who can do the following finite state machine problem with fewer states?

Tags: digital-logic, design

I encountered a problem about finite state machines in digital design which asks the following :

Design a sequential circuit with serial input X and serial outputs Z1 and Z2
which performs the following operation. Whenever the circuit receives a sequence 1100 on input it should output Z1 = 1 and Z2 = 0. Whenever the circuit receives a sequence 0101 on input it should output Z1 = 0 and Z2 = 1. Otherwise it should output Z1 = 0 and Z2 = 0. Draw the state diagram.

I found the folowing diagram. Is there anyone who can do this with fewer states?

[image]

Comment: No. 7 states is the minimum for a Moore machine. A Mealy machine would only require 6 states.

Comment: You need to correct the state diagram before you worry about minimizing.  From the initial state the [101] should not give a [10] output because the first 0 from the [0101] input is missing.

Comment: I understand your point but i can not find a solution. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So start out with a start state.  1 goes towards 1100 sequence.  0 goes towards 0101 sequence.  It is really hard if you do **NOT** try.  It becomes surprisingly easy when you do something.

Comment: Ok, let's try to fix this in steps.  If you are in init, a 0 should not return to init, it should go to the first state of [0101].  Out of curiosity what kind of class is this for? This is more complicated than the problems for any switching circuits class I've seen in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. This is digital design course that is given to second year students in EE majors. I think i fix my problem. There are 8 states in moore machine which has also initial state as well

Comment: Yes, that is what I got.  There is a total of nine states.

Answer (score 1):

S: initial node

A0..A3 represents the 0101 sequence

B0..B3 represents the 1100 sequence

The two digites after the state's name colon represent the output;

00 >> Z1=0, Z2=0

[image]

Drawn using graphviz

Comment: This is not quite right because the sequence [010101] should end up in A3 twice and it does not.

Comment: @owg60 yes you are right I have edited it.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat No it is not wrong, it is the same of your duplicated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing via DIA.  I had to post this because I worked it out.

[image]